# Scrollbar in user control

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I have a simple user control like this:

[image]

And yes, it has nothing inside, the controls will be dynamically added inside the user control using below on control load event:

```
List<Control> controlsNeed = getUserControls();
foreach(Control c in controlsNeed)
{
    this.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

The controls loaded correctly, but if there're many controls, there won't be enough space and scroll bars will be needed.

The problem is, the scroll bar isn't added to the control despite setting the below:

1. Setting AutoScroll to true in the user control
2. Try setting AutoSize to false and true

What settings / code should be added to add scrollbar to the control?

Comment: @T.S. Oh that's very simple, I just set the Control.Dock property to Bottom, and the controls will be appended to the bottom..

Comment: @T.S. Why? If more controls are added, they will only append to the bottom, won't they..?

Comment: Are you inheriting any other base control in this user control?

Comment: @Shell No, this is a stand alone user control, no other inheritation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Control> controlsNeed = getUserControls();
int PaddingTop = 10;
foreach (Control c in controlsNeed)
{
this.Controls.Add(c);
c.Location = new Point(0, c.Height + PaddingTop);
}
```

Or you can inherit the Panle control to your user control that will work like a panel control

```
public partial class MyControl : Panel
{
}
```

Comment: What is `Form1`? Are you really trying to dock a form?

Answer (score 3):

I think adding `AutoScrollMinSize` to user control should solve the problem

```
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AutoScrollMinSize=new Size(0,1);
        AutoScroll = true;
    }
```